# How to Using Map in Apex Salesforce?

Tags: apex

Iam New in Salesforce and I want to make schedule apex to update if there is QPD with invalid SAP ID.
It running well in my code with using list, but i want to change it to Map, i tried a few times but still cant figure it out.

it really means if u guys can help me how to figure it out, thanks

```
    List<Quotation_Product_Detail__c> listQPD = new List<Quotation_Product_Detail__c>();
    List<Prospect_Product_Detail__c> listPPD = new List<Prospect_Product_Detail__c>();
    List<Quotation_Product_Detail__c> listinvalidQPD = new List<Quotation_Product_Detail__c>();
    List<Quotation_Product_Detail__c> updateQPD = new List<Quotation_Product_Detail__c>();
    List<Id> invalidQPD = new List<ID>();
    
    listQPD = [SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate, Prospect__c, Prospect_Product__c, Prospect_Product_Delivery__r.SAP_ID__c, SAP_ID__c, Sub_Item__c 
               FROM Quotation_Product_Detail__c ]; //WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY
    if(listQPD.size() > 0){
        for (Quotation_Product_Detail__c notValidQPD: listQPD){
            if(notValidQPD.SAP_ID__c != notValidQPD.Prospect_Product_Delivery__r.SAP_ID__c){
               listinvalidQPD.add(notValidQPD);
               invalidQPD.add(notValidQPD.Prospect__c); //get QPD invalid SAP ID
            }
        }  
    }
    if(invalidQPD.size()> 0){
        listPPD = [SELECT Id,Prospect__c, SAP_ID__c FROM Prospect_Product_Detail__c WHERE Prospect__c IN :invalidQPD];
        if (listPPD.size()>0){
            for(Quotation_Product_Detail__c finalListQPD: listinvalidQPD){
                for(Prospect_Product_Detail__c finalListPPD: listPPD){
                    if(finalListQPD.Prospect_Product_Delivery__c == finalListPPD.Id){
                        finalListQPD.SAP_ID__c = finalListPPD.SAP_ID__c;
                        updateQPD.add(finalListQPD);
                    }
                }
            }
            update updateQPD;
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you really mean to match by Id, you already have the data you need, so just copy it directly:

```
List<Quotation_Product_Detail__c> updateQPD = new List<Quotation_Product_Detail__c>();
for (Quotation_Product_Detail__c notValidQPD: [
        SELECT Prospect_Product_Delivery__r.SAP_ID__c, SAP_ID__c 
        FROM Quotation_Product_Detail__c ]){
    if(notValidQPD.SAP_ID__c != notValidQPD.Prospect_Product_Delivery__r.SAP_ID__c){
        updateQPD.add(notValidQPD);
        notValidQPD.SAP_ID__c = notValidQPD.Prospect_Product_Delivery__r.SAP_ID__c;
    }
}  
update updateQPD;
```

If you mean to update by some other value, then a map might be more appropriate, but it's not necessary to do any extra queries here.

Comment: Wow, that so cool, its more simple and clean.
thank you so much, i learned something new from this